# python find() fails to find substring at start of string

Tags: python, anaconda

I have encountered some odd behavior with `find`. When searching for a substring, if that substring is at the very beginning of the string I am searching (the substring starts at index 0), it will not be found. If I pad the string with a single whitespace character (so the substring starts at index 1), it rescues find functionality and behaves as expected. Am I using `find` incorrectly?

```
my_string = "hello world"
searches = ["hello",
            "world",
            ]
# Search the string for the two substrings
for search in searches:
    if my_string.find(search):
        print("Found", search)
    else:
        print("Did not find", search)
# Did not find hello
# Found world

# Try padding the string, so substring 'hello' is not at the very beginning
my_padded_string = " " + my_string
for search in searches:
    if my_padded_string.find(search):
        print("Found", search)
    else:
        print("Did not find", search)
# Found world
# Found hello
```

Note the order of the substrings in the `searches` list does not seem to matter.

I am using Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit).

Comment: It does find it, find returns the index 0, which is falsey, you need to check if it returns -1 ie, not found

Comment: You can use `search in my_string`

Comment: Your test should be `if my_string.find(search) >= 0` instead.

Comment: This is just a failure to read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) on OP's part.

Comment: @MadPhysicist indeed, a lacks research flag would be useful

Comment: @NickA, I believe that the off topic flag " This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting" covers the issue pretty well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`find`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) is actually working as intended. It is supposed to return the index of the string if found and -1 otherwise.

Your `if` statement should read as follows:

```
for search in searches:
    if my_string.find(search) >= 0:
        print("Found", search)
    else:
        print("Did not find", search)
```